# How can i find angle between two circle points in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am working in cocos2dx game developing and working on circle gesture detection . I would like to ask how can I find angle between two points.How can i find angle between two points A and B.my ccTouchesMoved event as follows.

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent)
{

    CCLog("Touches moved");

    CCTouch *touch = (CCTouch*)pTouches->anyObject();

    location = touch->getLocation();

    location=CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

    prevLocation=CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(touch->getPreviousLocationInView());

    deltax=prevLocation.x-location.x;//difference of x

    deltay=prevLocation.y-location.x;//difference of y

    angle=??// i want this angle using deltax and deltay

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include math header and you can calculate angle in degree using formula:

```
angle = atan2 (deltay, deltax) * (180 / PI);
```

Comment: What is the math library?

Comment: @ThePoet Sorry I mean math header `<math.h>`